# Saving Data To Sitecore Analytics From Custom Code

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have been using Sitecore for a couple of years, and now looking to begin utilizing the Experience functionality found in Sitecore 8.

I have a view that will capture some user-provided data.   How do I go about creating a "person" (don't know the correct Sitecore terminology) in the Analytics database from custom code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to create a Contact. Contacts are a kind of profile store for xDb and allows you to store data about your visitors. A contact has a built in list of facets (email, phone number, name etc) that make up the contact record, but it's also possible to create your own facets.

If you are building a form to capture data you can use the new Tracker api to identify and update facets on a contact.

Here's some code to do this:

https://github.com/ianjohngraham/CoreBlimey.Utils/blob/master/CoreBlimey.Utils/xDB%20Contact%20Creator/CreateContact.aspx.cs

There's a walk through of how the code fits together here:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Jq6TpMgUGAk

(Apologies for the sound quality)

Also if you are using the WFFM module in Sitecore 8 there are some new save actions that will create contacts and store xDB data.

Comment: Awesome!   This was very helpful.  A few questions.   What does the "Personal" (after `<IContactPersonalInfo>`) refer to.  Is it always Personal or can it be other things.

How do you go about adding an Address.  I have `contactAddresses.Entries.Create().Country = registrationModel.Country` ... but it is expecting some sort of string inside the Create() part.

Lastly, how do you go about adding an additional field.   For example if I also wanted to track "Industry".

Comment: Here's a good one on creating your own facet which you will need for industry data: http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2014/09/Introducing-Contact-Facets.aspx

Comment: Personal is the name of the facet that is defined in your  Sitecore.Analytics.Model.config file. This post on the community docs should give you a good idea on how to add the entries: http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/xDB/contact-facets/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to spend time on the docs. Please refer [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/personalization) for articles and guides related to Personalization and Personas.

Most of the configuration can be specified in Experience Analytics within Sitecore and you can leverage Rules Engine to perform actions.